# Adding new nodes to Orderer Service Network (OSN)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

My question is simple - once the Orderer Service Network is created and is up and running, is it possible to extend it with new nodes acting as Orderers, Kafkas and Zookeepers?

The scenario I am thinking is when each participant in the network owns a stake at both peer and OSN layer. Therefore, a new participant should join the network with both peer(s), orderer(s), kafka node(s) and zookeeper node(s).

I am aware of recommended limits related to the size of Kafka/Zookeeper cluster; however, I am curious about technical possibility of successfully executing the above scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible:

If you add an orderer node you need it to wait to synchronize via fetching the transactions from kafka.

If you add a zookeeper node, well - consult the zookeeper manual, but - it's possible.

I haven't tried but i guess it should be the same for kafka too.

Comment: do you have an example of multiple orderers connected to a kafka cluster, that we can take a look? Whatever sample I found is one orderer and a kafka cluster. Thanks